# no operator “<=” matches these operands

Tags: c++

The entire project a long, so I've just included the relevant lines.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

string list[50][50];
string a, b;

for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
    cout << "Insert a" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Insert b" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    list[i][i] = {
                {a},
                {b}
    };
}
```

The assignment operator "=" is the only thing that has an error. The error is: "no operator "=" matches these operands. Operand types are: std::string = {...}"

I can't figure out what the issue here is. If I run the program anyway, it assigns "a" correctly, but not "b."

Comment: You can't insert two strings into the same place. Also, with the indexing you have now, it would only fill the diagonal of your array.

Comment: Your title says `<=` but your text says `=`.

Comment: What do you think that line does? The thing on the left holds a single string but the thing on the right is two strings. How can you set one equal to the other?

Comment: It seems to me you want to do a different thing.You are only filling a diagonal on the `list` variable.

Comment: Don't randomly extract lines that you think are relevant (you don't know what the issue is, so you're not qualified!) Present your [MCVE]. If you don't have one yet, you haven't finished your own debugging! :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you're confused by using a 2D array.  I think what you want is something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
    cout << "Insert a" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Insert b" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    list[i][0] = a;
    list[i][1] = b;
 }
```

Looking further at your code it could be more adaptable:

```
std::string list[50][50];
std::string a , b;
int innerArraySize = 2;
for ( int i = 0; i<50; i++ ) 
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < innerArraySize; j++ )
    {
        cout << "Insert " << (char)( j + 'a' );
        cin >> list[i][j];
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not compile.  Raw arrays are not assignable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an array of 50 arrays of 2?
Then you should do something like this:

```
string list[50][2];
// . . .
list[i][0] = a;
list[i][1] = b;
```

Comment: This does not compile.  Raw arrays are not assignable.

Comment: I think he/she wants to have 50x50 matrix.